# Why doesn't viscosity depend on pressure in the Navier-Stokes equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, continuum-mechanics, viscosity, navier-stokes

In the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations, we make an assumption on the stress in the fluid:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{Du}{Dt} &= \nabla \cdot \sigma\\
\sigma &= -pI + 2\mu e\\
e &= \frac12(\nabla u + \nabla u^\intercal)\\
\nabla \cdot u &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
such that the (local) rate of dissipation $||e||^2$ depends only on the strain-rate $e$. But in an incompressible fluid, for an arbitrary pair of adjacent fluid "elements" (a hand-wavy picture of "particles" or material points in the fluid), if dissipation is due to sliding friction:

[image]

and I imagine that pressure $p$ induces a normal force pushing or pulling these two elements apart, shouldn't the rate of dissipation depend not only on the strain rate but also the pressure? In particular, shouldn't it be that
$$
\mu = \mu(p),\ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial p} > 0
$$
Shouldn't this be the correct constitutive relation for the fluid? Where are my assumptions going wrong?

As a note, I'm interested in this question because of possible blow-up of the Navier-Stokes with well-behaved initial conditions. Perhaps if the dissipation rate is controlled with pressure, this type of blowup might not happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pressure dependence of viscosity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/580655/)

Comment: @KyleKanos This question does not ask IF it depends pn presssure but WHY it does not. The answers theree provide very little reasoning why it does not.

Comment: @KyleKanos Not quite. However, incidentally Vladimir's answer in that post did provide me some insight into where the sliding-friction intuition goes wrong, in that intermolecular distance (and therefore repulsion) does not exhibit a strong dependence on pressure in incompressible liquids.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general. We usually take viscosity coefficients as constant or a function of temperature only (try to have a look at Sutherland's law, $\mu(T)$), because this is the behaviour it's observed over a wide range of parameters covering a lot of applications of interest.

Being a thermodynamic quantity, viscosity is usually a function of the thermodynamic state and thus at least of two independent thermodynamic state variables.

At high pressure conditions, fluids may show a dependence of viscosity coefficients on temperature **and** pressure, namely

$\mu(T,P)$

Answer (score 1):

Sliding friction isn't a good model for shear in a fluid. Otherwise, water at great depths would behave radically differently from water at the surface.

The better question may be, why does pressure appear in sliding friction? One reason is that dry friction due to surface roughness has mechanical work performed against that contact pressure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).